# How to send signal or message from one device to another without server

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm sorry I don't know how to phrase this correctly.

Basically, I'm trying to work on an app that will send signals to another device that has the same app.

I want it to be able to connect via a user ID, or a code, something like that.

After connecting and recording the signal(a combination of button presses) I want it to send that signal to the phone that has the same app installed and I want that phone to do an action.
so it should be:
1)Record the button presses
2)After hitting the send button, send the signal(combination of presses)
3)The other phone that has the same application receives the code and reacts as it should.

is there anyway to make this without buying a server specifically for this?
Sorry for the "noob" questions and thanks for reading.

Comment: I found this site, http://elsoufy.blogspot.fr/2012/12/push-notifications-with-parsecom.html that is a blog that I THINK will help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You need the  server and client for communication ,  you can't reposnd to a client request without a server, also the client needs to know his server address, so if each client must know about the server address, its a good practice to have one server that knows about all the devices with your app installed and all clients know the address of that server, another option which is not recommended, is that your app will act as server and client which is ok if you only have two devices, but if you have more how can they all know to which server to address?

Comment: Yes, I was only planning on having 2 devices connect to each other at a time. But since you mentioned a server, I'll have to figure out how to do it how you explained, maybe.

Comment: You can try this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html